# Saving and increment data to MongoDB with $inc

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, increment

I have a blog application using Node.js, Mongoose, MongoDB and MongoDB Compass.
My aim is to count how many views each posts have.
For this I have created a 'Post' model schema and of course a route to the post.
I also found out that there is a $inc method to increment a value in the database.
https://medium.com/@salonimalhotra1ind/how-to-increment-a-number-value-in-mongoose-785066ba09d8

My problem is that I want to increment the default 0 value but for some reason when I check the value is still 0.

It must be something very simple I tried a few different ways but still not counting.
Any idea for this matter is much appreciated!
Thank you!

This is the schema with the 'viewCount':

```
const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose');
const UrlSlugs = require('mongoose-url-slugs');

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    category: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'categories'
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    slug: {
        type: String
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'public'
    },
    allowComments: {
        type: Boolean,
        require: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    file: {
        type: String
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    dateToApply: {
        type: Date
    },
    viewCount: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    comments: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'comments'
    }]
}, {usePushEach: true});

PostSchema.plugin(UrlSlugs('title', {field: 'slug'}));

try {
    module.exports = model('posts', PostSchema);
} catch (e) {
    module.exports = model('posts');
}
```

And the route the leads to a post with $inc:

```
router.get('/post/:slug',(req, res) => {
    Post.findOneAndUpdate({slug : req.params.slug}, {$inc : {viewCount : 1}});
    Post.findOne({slug: req.params.slug})
        .populate({path: 'comments', populate: {path: 'user', model: 'users'}})
        .populate('user')
        .then(post => {
            return Category.find({})
                .then(categories => {
                    res.render('home/post', {post: post, categories: categories});
                });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is because `findOneAndUpdate` is an async function, meaning your next call to `findOne` will run before the update is complete.

You either need to call `.then(() => Post.findOne(...` after your `findOneAndUpdate` call to wait for the result, or even better just use the `{new: true}` flag on `findOneAndUpdate` like so:

```js
router.get('/post/:slug',(req, res) => {
    Post.findOneAndUpdate({slug : req.params.slug}, {$inc : {viewCount : 1}}, {new: true})
        .populate({path: 'comments', populate: {path: 'user', model: 'users'}})
        .populate('user')
        .then(post => {
            return Category.find({})
                .then(categories => {
                    res.render('home/post', {post: post, categories: categories});
                });
        });
});
```